# Is there a way to copy/paste references from one project to another in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I know the Power Commands extension did that before, but that project seems to be inactive.

Comment: Copy the relevant section of the project file?

Comment: Well, sure. But isn't there a faster way? Like an extension that does that in the IDE? Preferably with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.

Comment: @GSerg that works, but is cumbersome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Power Commands were rolled into the [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d).

> ### Copy/Paste References
>
> Copies/Pastes one or more references to/from the clipboard. It can be executed from the references node, a single reference node or set of reference nodes.